# is it possible to store a ipa file in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, backup, ipa

Are we able to download a file from iPhone and able to save it in a specific location, if so how ?

In general it can be done at android mobile environments,is it possible to store a ipa file in iphone as a backup or for later installation?

is it possible to reproduce the same here at iphone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can install IPA in your iPhone or iPad. then import that ipa file to your iTunes. here i attached link for step by step tutorial. i followed this

[Installing applications with IPA files on iTunes (v2)](http://www.itexico.com/blog/bid/95555/Mobile-Tips-Installing-applications-with-IPA-files-on-iTunes-v2)

Edited:

steps as same in window if you are messed up. use the below link

[how-to-install-ipa-file-to-iphone-ipod by mac or windows](http://jaym2503.blogspot.in/2012/09/how-to-install-ipa-file-to-iphone-ipod.html)

Comment: it can be done only if the mac is present,for other systems like windows or in the mobile,the above method seems valid with respective to mac system mate,any alternative for windows system/iphone

Answer (score 1):

You can not get installed applications `.ipa` files from device. If you are working on any project who supports `.ipa` file just like `.doc` or `.txt` then
you can keep `.ipa` file in your device just as a file not for what it actually does. If you want to run it on your device you need a valid provisioning profile to be installed in your device. Your device udid should be added in that profile.

**Note: Answer is about title of your question. If you want to download the `.ipa` file from device then its not possible.**

Answer (score 1):

Short answer : NO

Long answer:

Only way of directly installing an .ipa file  from internet to your iPhone is when you have a link to an ipa file which has been published using an enterprise ad-hoc license. In that case you can directly download ipa files from internet and install without any hassle. Testflight uses this similar concept for beta testing ipa files.

Otherwise you need to downlaod the ipa file into your iTunes Software and sync it to your phone. Still app works only if that ipa file has been purchased from your apple id before.(eg: ipa transferred to another computer). Or, if that ipa file contains UDID of your device (this is how we beta test ipa files normal way).

If you never purchased the app (.ipa) or does not have your UDID embeded in the ipa itself,  no .ipa file works for your phone unless your phone is jailbroken and required cydia packages are already installed (illegal way).

Answer (score -1):

yes, you can save the .ipa file but it can only be installed on the devices which are authenticated from the mail-id you have purchased this app.

you can not save .ipa on your system.